# How to avoid italic texts (using \textit{}) out of margin for a double column document?

Tags: formatting, margins, italic

I am using `\textit{}` for some texts but it seems that the italic texts disregard the double column margin as shown in the following:

[image]

The code is as following:

```
It can be set by the user by setting a range 
\textit{vehicle\_waypoint\_follower\_min/max\_i}.
```

The document class is `acmart`.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please edit your posting to show the code that gives rise to the screenshot you posted. Please also tell us which document class you employ.

Comment: there are various things that can stop linebreaking, but italic font almost certainly unrelated, most likely it is the way you are making up `/` and `_` but as you have not shown your input hard to guess.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Thanks for pointing this out! I notice that it is indeed caused by _

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\usepackage{underscore}
```

allows your original input to work well. Breaks are allowed after underscore, and the individual words may be hyphenated. Breaks after the underscore display a hyphen character unless the package is loaded like `\uspackage[nohyphen]{underscore}`. This applies to both the `\_` command and the underscore character.

There are some repercussions for using "_" in cite/ref tags or in file names, but they are mostly alleviated by

```
\usepackage{babel}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone for help! As pointed out by @David Carlisle, it indeed has nothing to do with \textit{}. It is casued by my usage of `\_`. When I use `\renewcommand\_{\textunderscore\allowbreak}`, the problem is solved.

Comment: @daleif How? I can't see how this would affect anything, because `\_` is being redefined. Probably not what I'd do myself, but harmless.

Comment: @daleif Since the OP has edited the post, your comment has become misleading.